# Why is the constructor not accepted?

Tags: java, constructor

The instructions are
The Bullet class's constructor must initialize the dy field to -1 if the constructor's direction parameter is equal to Direction.UP.
The Bullet class's constructor must initialize the dy field to 1 if the constructor's direction parameter is not equal to Direction.UP.

My solution was

```
public Bullet(double x, double y, Direction direction) {
        super(x, y);
        setMatrix(ShapeMatrix.BULLET);
    if (Direction direction  == Direction.UP) {
        dy = -1;
    } else {
        dy = 1;
    }
```

But the correct solution was

```
    public Bullet(double x, double y, Direction direction) {
        super(x, y);
        setMatrix(ShapeMatrix.BULLET);
        this.dy = direction == Direction.UP ? -1 : 1;
    }
```

Can someone explain to me why?

Answer (score 1):

`this` inside the constructor would refer to the new object being created and returned. In the first scenario :

```
 dy = -1;
 dy = 1;
```

these values are being created globally and attached to the window object. You ideally want them on your object and that is why `this.dy` works

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `this` to reference the object's properties. `dy` hasn't been defined in the constructor's scope.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 1):

In your `if statement`, the `Direction direction` means you're initializing a variable

Just do `if (direction == Direction.Up)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `this` keyword when trying to access any class variables inside the constructor or any other function. Your code also works just access the `dy` property by `this` keyword only. Like the following

```
if (Direction direction  == Direction.UP) {
        this.dy = -1;
    } else {
        this.dy = 1;
    }
```

On the other hand in the provided solution is just that guy who just used the ternary operator as a shorthand of `if else` block nothing else.